# MSBUILD 4.0 Fails on AJAX Extensions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-ajax, msbuild

We have a .Net 2.0 web app and are converting the solution and projects to Visual Studio 2010 (they were Visual Studio 2005).  We are leaving the project targeting Framework 2.0.  The app includes Ajax extensions.  We did the conversion and can build the project successfully on the server using Visual Studio.  However, when we attempt to build the project through MSBUILD 4.0, we get errors on pages where ajax controls are used, such as the following:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9):
> warning MSB3267: The primary reference
> "System.Web.Extensions,
> Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL", which is
> a framework assembly, could not be
> resolved in the currently targeted
> framework.
> ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0". To
> resolve this problem, either remove
> the reference "System.Web.Extensions,
> Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL" or
> retarget your application to a
> framework version which contains
> "System.Web.Extensions,
> Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL".
> [C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\gmrcwebsite\GMRCWebsite.vbproj]
>
> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9):
> warning MSB3268: The primary reference
> "System.Web.Extensions.Design,
> Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not
> be resolved because it has an indirect
> dependency on the framework assembly
> "System.Web.Extensions,
> Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" which
> could not be resolved in the currently
> targeted framework.
> ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0". To
> resolve this problem, either remove
> the reference
> "System.Web.Extensions.Design,
> Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL" or
> retarget your application to a
> framework version which contains
> "System.Web.Extensions,
> Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35".
> [C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\gmrcwebsite\GMRCWebsite.vbproj]
>
> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9):
> warning MSB3268: The primary reference
> "AjaxControlToolkit,
> Version=1.0.10618.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not
> be resolved because it has an indirect
> dependency on the framework assembly
> "System.Web.Extensions,
> Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" which
> could not be resolved in the currently
> targeted framework.
> ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0". To
> resolve this problem, either remove
> the reference "AjaxControlToolkit,
> Version=1.0.10618.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL" or
> retarget your application to a
> framework version which contains
> "System.Web.Extensions,
> Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35".
> [C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\gmrcwebsite\GMRCWebsite.vbproj]
>
> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9):
> warning MSB3267: The primary reference
> "System.Web.Extensions.Design,
> Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL", which is
> a framework assembly, could not be
> resolved in the currently targeted
> framework.
> ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0". To
> resolve this problem, either remove
> the reference
> "System.Web.Extensions.Design,
> Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL" or
> retarget your application to a
> framework version which contains
> "System.Web.Extensions.Design,
> Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL".
> [C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\gmrcwebsite\GMRCWebsite.vbproj]
>
> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9):
> warning MSB3268: The primary reference
> "AjaxControlToolkit,
> Version=1.0.10618.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not
> be resolved because it has an indirect
> dependency on the framework assembly
> "System.Web.Extensions.Design,
> Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" which
> could not be resolved in the currently
> targeted framework.
> ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0". To
> resolve this problem, either remove
> the reference "AjaxControlToolkit,
> Version=1.0.10618.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL" or
> retarget your application to a
> framework version which contains
> "System.Web.Extensions.Design,
> Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35".
> [C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\gmrcwebsite\GMRCWebsite.vbproj]
>
> ...
>
> error BC30451: 'ScriptManager' is not
> declared. It may be inaccessible due
> to its protection level. error
> BC30002: Type
> 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' is not
> defined.  error BC30002: Type
> 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel' is not
> defined.  error BC30002: Type
> 'System.Web.UI.UpdateProgress' is not
> defined.

This stuff worked fine before and builds and works fine when built through Visual Studio.  What do we need to do to fix these errors?

Comment: Having this same issue, and our Web service will not compile at a later point due to the same issues.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just had the same problem myself after configuring TFS Build service 2008 to use MSBuild 4.0. Everything worked before converting the projects, after then conversion to 2010 format and the switch to MSBuild 4 suddenly it couldn't find the 1.0.61025.0 AJAX libraries.

It turned out there was a registry key missing that pointed to the install location of MS Ajax extensions.

On my **dev box** the key that should be located at (64-bit OS)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727\AssemblyFoldersEx\ASP.NET AJAX Extensions
```

was instead placed in HKEY_CURRENT_USER. (32-bit OS: remove the Wow6432Node part)

On the **build server** the key was missing completely (none of the locally present user profiles had it in its registry hive).

The default value of this key should point to the MS Ajax Extensions installation directory, which in my case is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions\v1.0.61025
```

**After recreating the key on the build server, our solution builds successfully under MSBuild 4.**

It remains a mystery to me why it built successfully until now (under MSBuild 3.5). Perhaps the assembly search algorithm changed slightly and is now more restrictive.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 : This worked for me - no idea why this works or didn't work before

Comment: Awesome - works a treat, as Chris says why on earth did it work before!

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you so much--this just solved 30 minutes of headache in one fell swoop.  =)

Answer (score 1):

Hello here you'll find the solution: http://www.developerit.com/2010/04/19/ms-ajax-libraries-and-configured-assemblies